Quickly navigation to any word in the viewport with only a few keystrokes
There are plugins like easymotion where you can do a quick search for 2 or so characters, and it highlights over every word with 2 characters which you can type to navigate to. I would like something like that, but for any word in the viewport.


Hop.nvim can do this: https://github.com/smoka7/hop.nvim. I was suggested a keymap here which works
    vim.keymap.set('', '<Space>w',
      function() require('hop').hint_words() end,
      { remap = true, desc = 'move to word in buffer' })

